# Python debugging advice

Tags: python

Whenever I try to run the code, nothing is displayed on the console. Can someone help identify the error

```
question_prompts = [
    "What is the name of our galaxy ? \n a. Milky Way \n b. Andromeda \n c. 
     Whirlpool"
    "Which star is closest to Earth ? \n a. Sun \n b. Moon \n c. Mars"
    "Which planet is called the blue planter \n a. Mars \n b. Earth \n c. 
     Neptune ?"

    ]
class Question :
  def __init__(self , prompt , answer):
    self.prompt = prompt 
    self.answer = answer 

    questions = [
           Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
           Question(question_prompts[1], "a"),
           Question(question_prompts[2], "b"),
    ]

def runTest(questions) :
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer :
            score += 1
    print("Your score is " + str(score) + "out of 3")
```

Comment: Is this your full code? Otherwise runTest is never called.

Comment: You don't seem to be calling any function or method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something to actually call the function you've defined. One way to do this is just to write at the end of your file:

```
runTest(question_prompts)
```

The more 'best practice' way is to include these lines at the end of the file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And then have a function in your file like this:

```
def main():
    runTest(question_prompts)
```

The reason this method is preferred is that this way your code is only run if you run the file directly. If you import the file from another file then main won't run. Whereas by just calling the function directly without a main function, then the code will always run regardless of whether or not it has been imported.

Answer (score 0):

Several things can be considered:

1) As suggested in the comments, you should run the function runTest;

2) 
This:

```
questions = [
            Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
            Question(question_prompts[1], "a"),
            Question(question_prompts[2], "b"),
     ]
```

seems to be within the class. You can try to bring it out if you want it to
be accessible from outside.

3) Try to separate question prompts with commas.